# Drop-down not working with safariDriver on Safari 10

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, ios

Getting below error while accessing `drop-down`
Using `Safari 10 mac sierra` with apple

```
`safariDriver`

 Selenium Version 3.0.1

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout:
```

How to handle it. Is there any compatibility issue with these versions or what?

// Initialization of safari driver & All Capabilities which I used-

```
DesiredCapabilities safaricapabiCapabilities=new DesiredCapabilities().safari();
 
try
{
driver=new SafariDriver(safaricapabiCapabilities);
}catch(Exception e1)
{
testStepContinue(false,"createInstance() = "+"Unable to Start on Local");
System.out.println(e1);
}
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();  
localThread.set(driver); 
}
```

// accessing drop down

```
WebElement dropdown =  getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='programIdSelect']"));
Select sel = new Select(dropdown);
sel.selectByVisibleText("All");
```

//DOM Window

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div style="display: none; visibility: visible; padding;" id='programDiv'>
   
<div class="fieldLabel" id='programLabelDiv' style="padding-bottom: 5px"><label for="programIdSelect">Select Your Program</label></div>
<select id="programIdSelect" name="programId" style="margin-bottom: 13px;">
</select>
</div>
</td> 
</tr>​
```

Comment: got some code ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Added Code as asked, Please have a look